# How do you get an email address from a database and automatically insert it into an email service providers TO box?

Tags: php, html, email, textbox, project

I am trying to create a program that allows an admit to select a group of email addresses from a database and when a submit button is clicked yahoo will automatically open and the email addresses will be automatically placed inside the reciever text box. Is there any way to get data from a database and fill the searchbox? As i do not want the admin to have to copy and paste the entire email directory. Also i cant use an email server. It has to be a simple way of retrieving text from a database and pasting it into a searchbox.

Answer (score 0):

If they have webmail set up on their computer you can just use a simple mailto.

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com">Send email</a>
```

And you can add a subject and multiple address.

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?subject=This%20is%20the%20subject&cc=someone_else@example.com&body=This%20is%20the%20body">Send email</a>
```

source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
$emailList = '';
foreach ($selectedEmails as $email) {
    $emailList .= $email.'; ';
}
```

So this would be in the `$_POST` request after the form is submitted. It generates a variable with the text in it. In the case above, I've added a `;` to the end of it for separation. You can edit as needed, then output the variable `$emailList` wherever needed.